# Problems with the magento installation

Tags: magento

Whenever I open `localhost/testm`, where `testm` is the folder that contains all the magento files, the following error is displayed:

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 1202944296

Whenever I am refreshing the page the error number keeps on changing.

Comment: Check Magento's `var/report` folder for a file with the given number. Open it with a text editor and check the logged exception.

Comment: i checked that and found some common files that have error, setup.php, app.php and index.php have errors. Please help.

Comment: Please add the exception trace of the file to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Rename file **`local.xml.sample`** to **`local.xml`** 
**file location** : magentoRootDirectory/errors/

Comment: i did this but the same problem is coming again .

Answer (score 0):

Please check your server max_execution_time using phpinfo(); and increase it if its value is too less. I hope this will solve your problem

Thanks

Comment: I changed it from 30 to 120 and then to 1800 but I am encountering the same problem.

Comment: Can you please also check the memory limit?